# I am thinking of a reversible ring which is not central armendariz.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Some notions about these rings. A ring $R$ is said to be reversible if for any $a,b \in R$ satisfy $ab=0$ then $ba=0$.

Central Armendariz ring : $R$ is said to be Central Armendariz if whenever $f(x)g(x)=0$ then $a_ib_j\in Z(R)$, where $Z(R)$ is center of $R$ and $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i, g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{m}b_jx^j \in R[x]$. I am thinking about trivial extension $T(R,R)$ of a reduced ring $R$ but I am not able to construct the right example.